# Unable to update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> Could not initialize the package information
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

```
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-pt%5fBR, 
E:As listas de pacotes ou o ficheiro de status não pôde ser analisado ou aberto.
```

Comment: Please help me to update my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Delete the mergelists:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then run the package list update again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And update your system:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```